# Ghost Blog on Ubuntu Snappy Core OS

Tags: docker, vagrant, ubuntu-11.10, ghost-blog, ghost

I have Ghost Blog running inside a Snappy VM using these commands:
  vagrant init ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-stable
  vagrant up && vagrant ssh

docker pull ghost
  docker run -d -p 80:2368 -v /home/ubuntu/blog --name hello-world ghost

Now that the blog is running, how can I view it from the outside world?

Comment: use `docker ports container_id`, it il show you the port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin- what do you mean by "outside world"?

It looks like you started a virtual machine on your development machine using vagrant, and then fired up a docker container on that virtual machine.

Your docker command publishes the port ghost listens on (2368) to port 80 of the machine that docker is listening on.  That is NOT your dev machine though- it is the vagrant virtualbox!  This means that on your host machine you cannot run go to `localhost` to view your blog.  (Though, you could ping it from inside the virtualbox using that address...)

What you need to do is find the IP address of your vagrant virtualbox.  SSH in using `vagrant ssh`.  Then run `ifconfig` and get the IP address of your box.  (you'll need to know a bit here- my vagrant box actually shows this on eth1 instead of eth0)

You can make this easier in a few ways.  You can hard-code an ip address into your vagrantfile...

```
ip_address = "192.168.33.17"
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip_address
```

Further, you can use the vagrant plugin 'hostmanager' to specify a /etc/hosts entry on your machine that will allow you to point your browser at a hardcoded address and vagrant will always point it at the right machine.  If you have that installed (`vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager`)you can modify your vagrantfile with

```
  config.hostmanager.enabled = true
  config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
  config.vm.define project_name do |node|
    node.vm.hostname = "myghostblog.com"
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip_address
    node.hostmanager.aliases = [ "www.myghostblog.com" ]
  end
```

If you actually mean you want your blog to be visible from the public internet, that is not something you want to do on your private computer without a ton of knowledge that you don't have (or else you wouldn't need to ask :) ).

Comment: I edited the Vagrantfile and enabled the forwarded port mapping:    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080   ,   then vagrant reload and vagrant ssh,  Now I am logged into the Snappy VM, and start ghost again, docker run -d -p 80:2368 -v /home/ubuntu/blog --name test ghost , then verify the port mapping:  enter :  docker port be2f474bb8c9 , which reveals
2368/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80    At this point, I browse to localhost:8080 and see my ghost blog!  Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear it worked.  Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you out.

Comment: Check.  And now that I have changed the default Vagrant password, I'd like to go live.  This is a Ghost Blog running inside a Docker container on Ubuntu Snappy Core.  Inside a virtual machine.  On a bare-metal OS I can rebuild in minutes and there is a firmware protect screw on the hardware.  Am I ready to face the internet?  What did I miss?  How do I do it?  -thanks

Comment: It's highly not recommended, but if you are convinced you want to host a public facing website from your personal computer... you need to have a static ip address.  You need to point your dns name at that static ip.  You need to forward the ghost port to a port on your physical machine (using virtualbox settings), and from there you have to forward THAT port to port 80 on your router.

Comment: As a random note, if you're running nothing on that os but your blog, the virtualbox is an unneccessary layer of abstraction, you can just run docker on the host machine.

Comment: Lots of malware dies off when it realizes it is in a virtual machine.  And the OS on the VM is Ubuntu Snappy Core, which is a harder nut to crack than my native Lubuntu.  So entreprenurial malware first has to break out of the Docker container, take over a write-protected minimalist linux core, or somehow otherwise break out of Virtualbox, and then take over my apt-get updated Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the Vagrantfile and enabled the forwarded port mapping: config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080 , then vagrant reload and vagrant ssh, Now I am logged into the Snappy VM, and start ghost again, docker run -d -p 80:2368 -v /home/ubuntu/blog --name test ghost , then do the port mapping: enter : docker port be2f474bb8c9 , which reveals 2368/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80 At this point, I was hoping to browse to localhost:8080 and see my ghost blog.
Thank you both!